# Rspec tests fail which should pass. Railstutorial.org chapter 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, railstutorial.org

I took a long break from programming, because other things caught my interest. When I picked it back up, I decided it would be a good idea to go back through railstutorial.org, since I found it useful the first time through, but couldn't remember much as I had hoped.

After simply running the command 'rails generate controller Pages home contact' I have a 'spec/controllers/pages_controllers_rspec.rb' file that looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Even though all the routes and controllers are in place as described in chapter 3, Rspec indicates failure. What am I doing wrong?

Both tests fail with messages:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
PGError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: I don't see any failure messages.

Comment: Issue resolved. I'll post the answer once I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test database hadn't been created. Don't ask me why. Once I'd gone back in and manually created the test database, tests started passing.